# WebKit GTK fails to compile on Apple Silicon

Tags: arm, webkit, apple-m1, apple-silicon, webkitgtk

I tried to build WebKit GTK on my ARM Mac, but the linking process fails:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_u_charDirection_67", referenced from:
      WTF::StringImpl::stripWhiteSpace() in libWTFGTK.a(StringImpl.cpp.o)
      WTF::StringImpl::simplifyWhiteSpace() in libWTFGTK.a(StringImpl.cpp.o)
      WTF::StringImpl::defaultWritingDirection(bool*) in libWTFGTK.a(StringImpl.cpp.o)
      int WTF::toIntegralType<int, char16_t>(char16_t const*, unsigned long, bool*, int) in libWTFGTK.a(WTFString.cpp.o)
      unsigned int WTF::toIntegralType<unsigned int, char16_t>(char16_t const*, unsigned long, bool*, int) in libWTFGTK.a(WTFString.cpp.o)
      long long WTF::toIntegralType<long long, char16_t>(char16_t const*, unsigned long, bool*, int) in libWTFGTK.a(WTFString.cpp.o)
      unsigned long long WTF::toIntegralType<unsigned long long, char16_t>(char16_t const*, unsigned long, bool*, int) in libWTFGTK.a(WTFString.cpp.o)
      ...
  "_u_foldCase_67", referenced from:
      WTF::StringImpl::foldCase() in libWTFGTK.a(StringImpl.cpp.o)
  "_u_strFoldCase_67", referenced from:
      WTF::StringImpl::foldCase() in libWTFGTK.a(StringImpl.cpp.o)
  "_u_strToLower_67", referenced from:
      WTF::StringImpl::convertToLowercaseWithoutLocale() in libWTFGTK.a(StringImpl.cpp.o)
      WTF::StringImpl::convertToLowercaseWithLocale(WTF::AtomString const&) in libWTFGTK.a(StringImpl.cpp.o)
  "_u_strToUpper_67", referenced from:
      WTF::StringImpl::convertToUppercaseWithoutLocale() in libWTFGTK.a(StringImpl.cpp.o)
      ...
      WTF::normalizedNFC(WTF::StringView) in libWTFGTK.a(StringView.cpp.o)
  "_unorm2_isNormalized_67", referenced from:
      WTF::normalizedNFC(WTF::StringView) in libWTFGTK.a(StringView.cpp.o)
  "_unorm2_normalize_67", referenced from:
      WTF::normalizedNFC(WTF::StringView) in libWTFGTK.a(StringView.cpp.o)
  "_utext_close_67", referenced from:
      WTF::setTextForIterator(UBreakIterator&, WTF::StringView) in libWTFGTK.a(TextBreakIterator.cpp.o)
      WTF::acquireLineBreakIterator(WTF::StringView, WTF::AtomString const&, char16_t const*, unsigned int, WTF::LineBreakIteratorMode) in libWTFGTK.a(TextBreakIterator.cpp.o)
      WTF::TextBreakIteratorICU::TextBreakIteratorICU(WTF::StringView, WTF::TextBreakIteratorICU::Mode, char const*) in libWTFGTK.a(TextBreakIterator.cpp.o)
  "_utext_setup_67", referenced from:
      WTF::openLatin1UTextProvider(WTF::UTextWithBuffer*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, UErrorCode*) in libWTFGTK.a(UTextProviderLatin1.cpp.o)
      WTF::openLatin1ContextAwareUTextProvider(WTF::UTextWithBuffer*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, char16_t const*, int, UErrorCode*) in libWTFGTK.a(UTextProviderLatin1.cpp.o)
      WTF::uTextLatin1Clone(UText*, UText const*, signed char, UErrorCode*) in libWTFGTK.a(UTextProviderLatin1.cpp.o)
      WTF::openUTF16ContextAwareUTextProvider(UText*, char16_t const*, unsigned int, char16_t const*, int, UErrorCode*) in libWTFGTK.a(UTextProviderUTF16.cpp.o)
      WTF::uTextCloneImpl(UText*, UText const*, signed char, UErrorCode*) in libWTFGTK.a(UTextProvider.cpp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [bin/WebKitWebDriver] Error 1
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. It compiled just fine on my Intel Mac. Any ideas on how to fix this?